# Make a pandas data-frame with percentage between two referential values in a set

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have pandas data-frame (df) and a list (df_values).

I want to make another data-frame which contains the distribution/percentage a data-point in df belongs to values in the list df_values.

data-frame df is:

```
     A
0  100
1  300
2  150
```

List df_values (set of referential values) is:

```
df_values = [[0,200,400,600]]
```

Desired data-frame:
Here number 100 in df is 0.50 towards 0 and 0.50 towards 200 in df_values. Similarly, 300 in df is 0.50 towards 200 and 0.50 towards 400 in df_values and so on.

```
      0   200  400  600
0  0.50  0.50  0.0    0
1  0.00  0.50  0.5    0
2  0.25  0.75  0.0    0
```

Comment: why your list is 2D? what is your definition of ```towards```?

Comment: It can be 1D `df_values = [0,200,400,600]`. Towards means: For example, 100 is between 0 and 200,  (|0-100|)/(200-0) = 0.50 and (|200-100|)/(200-0) = 0.50, respectively.